# I used variables but eslint said is defined but never used

Tags: typescript, eslint, nest, typescript-eslint

I'm using the variables in my code but when I run yarn lint, I get that we don't use them, Anyone know what might be happening ?

nest: 8.0

node: 14.7.3

slint: ^7.30.0

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  MICROSERVICES,
  ReadStoreMccSubCategoriesDto,
} from 'contants';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';

import { HttpClient } from '@commons/modules';
import { HttpMicroServiceProvider } from '@commons/service/http-micro-service-provider';

const { MCC_SUB_CATEGORY } = MICROSERVICES.STORES;
@Injectable()
export class StoreMccSubCategoriesService extends HttpMicroServiceProvider {
  constructor(@Inject(MICROSERVICES.STORES.NAME_HTTP) client: HttpClient) {
    super(client);
  }

  getMccSubCategories(): Observable<ReadStoreMccSubCategoriesDto[]> {
    return this.send(
      {
        directory: MCC_SUB_CATEGORY.NAME,
        path: MCC_SUB_CATEGORY.STORE_GET_MCC_SUB_CATEGORY,
      },
      {},
    );
  }

  getMccSubCategoryById(id: string): Observable<ReadStoreMccSubCategoriesDto> {
    return this.send(
      {
        directory: MCC_SUB_CATEGORY.NAME,
        path: MCC_SUB_CATEGORY.STORE_GET_MCC_SUB_CATEGORY_BY_CATEGORY,
      },
      { id },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]